# R function to create a new column with a value based on whether or not text is capitalized

Tags: r

I have a data frame df with 2 columns, x and y.

```
x <- c("ABC", "def", "GHI")
y <- c("jkl", "MNO", "pqr")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to add a column z, where the value of z = x if x is all uppercase, and z = y if x is all lowercase.

e.g. column Z in this example would be

```
ABC
MNO
GHI
```

The code that makes sense to me is the following:

```
df$z <- ifelse(identical(z$x, toupper(z$x)), z$x, z$y)
```

but this is just giving me a column z with the value "jkl" in each row.

Comment: `ifelse(df$x == toupper(df$x), df$x, df$y)`

Comment: Just `data.frame(x,y,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` will do. `cbind` will just cause everything to be forced to a `matrix` of one `class` first, which isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use

```
x <- c("ABC", "def", "GHI")
y <- c("jkl", "MNO", "pqr")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$z <- ifelse(df$x == toupper(df$x), df$x, df$y)
df$z 
# [1] "ABC" "MNO" "GHI"
```

However, this is not checking whether `df$y` is all lowercase or not. It just checks whether `df$x` is all upercase. If `df$x` is not uppercase, it will pick `df$y` no matter `df$y` is lowercase or not.

Comment: Thanks, Tomas. My data will always have one column uppercase and one column lowercase, so this works well. Looks like I was close, but you nailed it right on the head. Thanks for the quick turnaround. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `grepl` option

```
transform(df, Z = ifelse(grepl("^[A-Z]+$", x), x, y))
#    x   y   Z
#1 ABC jkl ABC
#2 def MNO MNO
#3 GHI pqr GHI
```